# c++ currency converter trailing zeroes

Tags: c++

i just started programming and wrote a currency converter programme that needs to be accurate to 2 decimals (using double) However i would not like trailing zeroes but users should still be able to input decimals with set precision rounding it off to a whole integer

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

const double DOLLAR = 0.05917;
const double EUROS = 0.05681;

int main()
{
double rand;
double equivD;
double equivE;

cout << setprecision(2)<<fixed;

cout << " Enter Rand amount: ";
cin >> rand;

cout << rand << " Rand(s)= ";
equivD= (rand*DOLLAR);
cout << equivD<< " Dollar(s)\n ";

cout << rand << " Rand(s)= ";
equivE= (rand*EUROS);
cout << equivE<< " Euro(s)\n ";

return 0;

}
```

Output if entered value is a 1000 is:

```
1000.00= 57.24 Dollars 
1000.00= answer
```

If an integer is inputed without decimals I would like to remove the `.00` but still keep it as a `double` in case a decimal is inputed. How do I do this?

Comment: Using floating-point numbers to represent money is generally not a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want different formatting for different cases, I would test to see if there is a decimal.

In your example, with *double*s, this could be

```
if( 0 == (((long long)(rand*100)) % 100) )
    cout << setprecision(0);
```

This multiplies *rand* by 100, converts it to an integral type, and then checks if the right two digits are both zero.

**The Better Solution**

Use an integral type (like *int* or *long long*) to store the value as "hundredths of rands" (like Bathsheba suggested). This reduces rounding errors. To test for the decimal and output, just use a modulo, like this:

```
cout << (rand / 100);    // Integer division
if( 0 != (rand % 100) )  // Are there any amounts less than one rand?
    cout << '.' << (rand % 100);
```

Of course, there is still the issue of reading in the user input to a *long long*, but I'm not an expert with *cin*.

Comment: is there no way to turn of show point to remove trailing zeroes?

Comment: If I understand, you are asking if a flag can be set to make _setprecision_ set the **maximum** precision instead of a **constant** precision. When using _fixed_, the precision is **constant** and refers to the digits to the right of the decimal. When using the default _floatfield_, the precision is the **maximum** and refers to digits both to the left **and** the right of the decimal. In short, the answer is no. [C++ _fixed_ keyword](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/fixed/)

Comment: I replaced the doubles test with a slightly less hacky version.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use floating point for money: you'll be off on the 15th significant figure; which, by the time you've consumed two digits for the cents, is not particularly large.

In your case, use a 64 bit integral type and work in cents, tweaking your *formatting* when you want to display computed values. (Don't forget to round correctly when using the FX rates).

Comment: I'm sorry I'm kind of a noob at programming x_x. so what should i change in this program? also what should i use for money, also the specification for my assignment is to put it in rands not cents

Comment: @moe7865: The idea here is to have a `class Money  { private: long long cents; ... }` but if you didn't cover classes yet that could be difficult.